# Bash is printing (only) one of my aliases before every prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I think this is the relevant bit of my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```

(I forget where I got this from so I sadly can't credit the source.) This is the only appearance of the line `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` in the `~/.bashrc` file.

The annoyance is: Whenever I open a prompt/terminal/bash, the terminal echoes

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

(but not the others!)
I would like to remove this notification.

**Edit:** Here are the other `profile` files I can find on the system.

```
#~/.bash_profile
#!/bin/bash
echo "You've got rhythm. You've got music. Anything else?"


#~/.profile
#unmask 022
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi



#/etc/profile
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi



if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Comment: What does `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` and/or `echo "$PS1"` show you? Those may be declared in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @glennjackman `$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$`

Comment: @glennjackman `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` yields nothing (blank line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652126/bashrc-profile-is-not-loaded-on-new-tmux-session-or-window-why and here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically

I needed to add `source ~/.bashrc` to the end of my `.bash_profile`.